# Inkwell showing two ripple effect

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
 PopupMenuItem(
            value: 1,
            height: 90.w,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  status = "Online";
                });
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, bottom: 3, left: 3, right: 3),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset("images/online_list.png",
                        width: 25.w, height: 25.w),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.w),
                      child: CustomText('Online', MyApp.subDetailTextSize,
                          FontWeight.w500, MyApp.blackText, 'Lato'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

So this is my code and when I click the item it shows ripple effect inside row and outside too i.e 2 ripple effect at same time. I want to remove the inner one which was around the row.

I tried removing container and its margin it didn't worked that way too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `highlightColor` and `splashColor` property inside `InkWell` like:

```
PopUpMenuItem(
    child: InkWell(
       highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
       splashColor: Colors.transparent,
       onTap: (){
           // Do your stuffs
       },
       child: // Your child widget
    ),
),
```

You can see all the properties of `InkWell`, [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html).